# Rails not picking up model attribute despite column EXISTING in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake, heroku

```
==  AddIpToTutorials: migrating ===============================================
-- add_column(:tutorials, :ip_address, :string)
   -> 0.0022s
==  AddIpToTutorials: migrated (0.0022s) ======================================

>> t = Tutorial.new
..
>> t.ip_address
NoMethodError: undefined method `ip_address' for #<Tutorial:0x2b3b35f5a690>
```

... What gives? >______>

Comment: Have you checked the DB to see if the new column exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up making a seperate migration and doing the same thing again.

Crumby, but it works...

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into the exact same problem, and instead of making a separate migration I would instead suggest running the command:

`heroku restart`

After running the above command heroku picked up the changes and my app worked as expected. Try this before going through the pain of rolling back a migration, deleting it, and then creating a new one.